# How to retrieve data from a JSON string for specific key

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am decoding a JSON file using php and trying to only get contents from the array where ID is `1234`.

For example:

```
  [
   {
      "id":"1234",
      "is_printed":"1",
      "is_refunded":"1",
      "order_products":[
         {
            "id":"xyz",
            "order_id":"xyz",
            "date_created":"3434"
         }
      ]
   },

      {
      "id":"8910",
      "is_printed":"1",
      "is_refunded":"1",
      "order_products":[
         {
            "id":"abcde",
            "order_id":"abcde",
            "date_created":"3434"
         }
      ]
   }

 ]
```

I would like to retrieve the `order_id` from the `order_products` only where id `1234`.

So I should only get `xyz` and not `xyz` AND `abcde`.

Comment: `json_decode` and `foreach` through it.

Comment: You have got syntax error in your json, you put `comma ','` even when you finish supper or subArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop and then get those that you want, making sure you check the level properly:

```
$jv = json_decode($v);

foreach ($jv as $t) {
   if ($t->id == 1234) {
      print $t->order_products[0]->order_id;
   }
}
```

Note I am using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first to convert the JSON string `$v` into something php can process.

What is the way to know that `print $t->order_products[0]->order_id;` was the index to look at? Well, I took your JSON and `var_dump`ed it. Then, by following the structure of the output you can see what is the exactly index you need.

---

See a full working code with your data:

```
$v='  [
{
    "id":"1234",
    "is_printed":"1",
    "is_refunded":"1",
    "order_products":[
        {
            "id":"xyz",
            "order_id":"xyz",
            "date_created":"3434"
        }
    ]
},

    {
    "id":"8910",
    "is_printed":"1",
    "is_refunded":"1",
    "order_products":[
        {
            "id":"abcde",
            "order_id":"abcde",
            "date_created":"3434"
        }
    ]
}

]';

$jv = json_decode($v);

foreach ($jv as $t) {
   if ($t->id == 1234) {
      print $t->order_products[0]->order_id;
   }
}

var_dump($jv);
```

It returns:

output:

```
xyz
```

dump:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1234"
    ["is_printed"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_refunded"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["order_products"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(3) "xyz"
        ["order_id"]=>
        string(3) "xyz"
        ["date_created"]=>
        string(4) "3434"
    }
    }
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#3 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "8910"
    ["is_printed"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_refunded"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["order_products"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "abcde"
        ["order_id"]=>
        string(5) "abcde"
        ["date_created"]=>
        string(4) "3434"
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The foreach fixed one of my problems but how do i retrieve "order_id" thats nestled under "order_products"? i tried what you put but it just didnt do anything. It wasn't a php error it was just blank.

Comment: Have you tried using `json_decode()` beforehand? It should make it. Also, try to do `var_dump($array)` to see what you have in it.

Comment: Yes i have used json_decode beforehand. 
using the code `echo  $object->{'order_products'};` it displays "Array" but `echo  $object->{'order_products'}{'order_id'};` doesnt work. niether does your version which would be `$object['order_products']['order_id'];`

Comment: What if you say `$object->{'order_products'}['order_id']`? Second one `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: Nothing. It's like the code is working but there is nothing in the Array - apart from the fact that there is something in the array.

Comment: I cannot see what you have in your data, so you should either update your question with the info or post it somewhere (pastebin, for example).

Comment: My data? I included my JSON in the OP thats the data. I then use `$data = json_decode($json);` to decode said data

Comment: The JSON you have is not valid, check it in JSON lint. Also, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do it, update your question and then we can check further.

Comment: The data is valid now, i can't show you the full data it's confidential. But this is the closest i can get to the environment. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use a foreach and loop the array

```
foreach ($yourArray AS $rowInArray) {
 if ($rowInArray['id'] == 1234 {
   //save the value to a global array
  }
}
```

other option is to use the "array_column()" function. I have not used this one before, but you can find information abut syntax here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

Using all previous answers there is your full code:

```
$orderId = array();
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row['id'] == 1234) {
        $orderId[] = $row['order_products']['order_id'];
    }
}
```